# CIL implementation of On Error Resume Next

Tags: .net, vb.net, cil

I've always wondered: How is the infamous VB.NET statement "On Error Resume Next" converted to CIL? Does it involve wrapping every line with try...catches?

Answer (score 3):

Goto.

You can't combine try-catch with the legacy error handling in one method. When you use `On Error Resume Next`, every single line of code in the method gets a label, as well as a unique identifier. In pseudo-C# code:

```
int currentId = 0;

Label1:
currentId = 1;
Line1();

Label2:
currentId = 2;
Line2();

Label3:
currentId = 3;
Line3();

Exit:
```

The whole method gets wrapped in a try catch. When the exception hits, the catch handler will check `currentId` and do a simple `goto` to the next label in line (and `ProjectError` is set). In our case, it would look something like this:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex);

  if (currentId == 1) goto Label2;
  if (currentId == 2) goto Label3;
  if (currentId == 3) goto Exit;
}
```

Mind you, this is just an implementation detail I got by decompiling an VB.NET application. The only contractual behaviour is the one defined in `On Error Resume Next`, which basically boils down to "set project error and continue to next statement".

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Public Sub A()
End Sub
Public Sub B()
End Sub
Public Sub C()
End Sub
Public Sub D()
End Sub
Public Sub E()
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    A()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    B()
    Exit Sub
    C()
    ErrorHandler:
    D()
    Resume Next
    E()
End Sub
```

Compiles to (without the supplementary methods):

```
.method public static void  Test() cil managed
{
  // Code size       201 (0xc9)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           int32 V_1,
           int32 V_2)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0001:  stloc.2
  IL_0002:  call       void VBTest.Program::A()
  IL_0007:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
  IL_000c:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_000d:  stloc.0
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_000f:  stloc.2
  IL_0010:  call       void VBTest.Program::B()
  IL_0015:  leave      IL_00c0
  IL_001a:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_001b:  stloc.2
  IL_001c:  call       void VBTest.Program::C()
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.6
  IL_0022:  stloc.2
  IL_0023:  call       void VBTest.Program::D()
  IL_0028:  ldc.i4.7
  IL_0029:  stloc.2
  IL_002a:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
  IL_002f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0030:  brtrue.s   IL_0047
  IL_0032:  ldc.i4     0x800a0014
  IL_0037:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Exception [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::CreateProjectError(int32)
  IL_003c:  throw
  IL_003d:  ldc.i4.s   9
  IL_003f:  stloc.2
  IL_0040:  call       void VBTest.Program::E()
  IL_0045:  leave.s    IL_00c0
  IL_0047:  ldloc.1
  IL_0048:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0049:  add
  IL_004a:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_004b:  stloc.1
  IL_004c:  switch     ( 
                        IL_007d,
                        IL_0000,
                        IL_0007,
                        IL_000e,
                        IL_0015,
                        IL_001a,
                        IL_0021,
                        IL_0028,
                        IL_003d,
                        IL_003d,
                        IL_0045)
  IL_007d:  leave.s    IL_00b5
  IL_007f:  ldloc.2
  IL_0080:  stloc.1
  IL_0081:  ldloc.0
  IL_0082:  switch     ( 
                        IL_0093,
                        IL_0047,
                        IL_0021)
  IL_0093:  leave.s    IL_00b5
  IL_0095:  isinst     [mscorlib]System.Exception
  IL_009a:  ldnull
  IL_009b:  cgt.un
  IL_009d:  ldloc.0
  IL_009e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_009f:  cgt.un
  IL_00a1:  and
  IL_00a2:  ldloc.1
  IL_00a3:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_00a4:  ceq
  IL_00a6:  and
  IL_00a7:  endfilter
  IL_00a9:  castclass  [mscorlib]System.Exception
  IL_00ae:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::SetProjectError(class [mscorlib]System.Exception)
  IL_00b3:  leave.s    IL_007f
  IL_00b5:  ldc.i4     0x800a0033
  .try IL_0000 to IL_0095 filter IL_0095 handler IL_00a9 to IL_00b5
  IL_00ba:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Exception [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::CreateProjectError(int32)
  IL_00bf:  throw
  IL_00c0:  ldloc.1
  IL_00c1:  brfalse.s  IL_00c8
  IL_00c3:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
  IL_00c8:  ret
} // end of method Program::Test
```

This abberation gets decompiled with Reflector to this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    int num2;
    try
    {
        int num3;
    Label_0000:
        num3 = 1;
        A();
    Label_0007:
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        int num = 2;
    Label_000E:
        num3 = 3;
        B();
        goto Label_00C0;
    Label_001A:
        num3 = 5;
        C();
    Label_0021:
        num3 = 6;
        D();
    Label_0028:
        num3 = 7;
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        if (num2 != 0)
        {
            goto Label_0047;
        }
        throw ProjectData.CreateProjectError(-2146828268);
    Label_003D:
        num3 = 9;
        E();
        goto Label_00C0;
    Label_0047:
        num2 = 0;
        switch ((num2 + 1))
        {
            case 1:
                goto Label_0000;

            case 2:
                goto Label_0007;

            case 3:
                goto Label_000E;

            case 4:
            case 10:
                goto Label_00C0;

            case 5:
                goto Label_001A;

            case 6:
                goto Label_0021;

            case 7:
                goto Label_0028;

            case 8:
            case 9:
                goto Label_003D;

            default:
                goto Label_00B5;
        }
    Label_007F:
        num2 = num3;
        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
                goto Label_00B5;

            case 1:
                goto Label_0047;

            case 2:
                goto Label_0021;
        }
    }
    catch (object obj1) when (?)
    {
        ProjectData.SetProjectError((Exception) obj1);
        goto Label_007F;
    }
Label_00B5:
    throw ProjectData.CreateProjectError(-2146828237);
Label_00C0:
    if (num2 != 0)
    {
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
    }
}
```

Aside from the fact that it uses a bunch of switches and gotos, I have no idea what that code actually does.